# C++: managing a set of objects so that the held objects can access the data structure holding them

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures

I store pointers to all instances of class `Cell` in a linked list. The `std::list<Cell*> cells` is stored in a class named `Game`. The method `Game::update()` iterates trought all instances of `Cell` held in the list `cells`, and calls each cell's `Cell::update()` method. If the `Cell::update()` method finds out at some point that the cell is ready to divide, it needs to `push_back()` a pointer to the new cell to `cells` in order for the new cell to be updateable.
But how can I refer to `Game::cells` within the `cell` in order to do that? I have considered the following options:

- Defining `std::list<Cell*> cells` in global scope instead.

  - nasty and makes it impossible to have more than one `Game`
- Making `std::list<Cell*> cells` a static member of `Cell`

  - better than the global var but still prevents the use of multiple `Game` instances
- Passing a reference to the current game's `Game::cells` as a parameter to the Cell's constructor and subsequently storing a copy of that reference in the newly constructed cell instance

  - I think it is a little inflexible
- Passing a reference to the current game's `Game::cells` as a parameter to the `Cell::update()` method

Are there more elegant solutions to utilize?

Comment: What about just returning whatever is needed from `Cell::update()` and then let `Game` push the new cells into the list?

Comment: I considered that but what would I return if the cell suffers a weird mutation and decides to divide into 4 parts?

Comment: A `std::vector<Cell>` would be a simple and straightforward solution. I wouldn't worry to much about performance at this point, just try to divide responsibilities and design the interface properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not introduce an unnecessary dependence between `Cell` and `Game`, if all `Game` does is to call methods on `Cell`s and hold instances of them.

You could instead return new `Cell`s (or none) from `Cell::update()` and let `Game` decide what to do, most probably add them to the list. You could also define a new function for this in `Cell`, something like `Cell::splitCell()` and let `Cell::update()` only update properties of `Cell` objects (as the name would suggest).

Answer (score 2):

I would probably pass a reference to the `Game` into `Cell::update()` and then tell the Game object to divide the cell, but other options may be better as I still don't think I have a full picture of what your overall goal is.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean, why manage the division in `Game::update()` instead of `Cell::update()` if I pass a reference to the instance of `Game` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference to `Game` into the `Cell` constructor.  Then make a function that lets a `Cell` push other `Cell` objects onto the list (or make `Cell` a friend class of `Game` so that it can access the list directly).

This way, `Cell` can decide when it needs to split, but it can delegate the action to the `Game` object where it belongs.

Also, if there are any future thing that the `Cell` might want the `Game` to do for it, he already has a hold of the right object.

Answer (score 0):

If Cell objects must know which Game object they belong to, derive a class from std::list<> and include a pointer to Game (Game *) as a member of Cell. Cell object can then use this pointer to add another Cell to th Game.

```
class Game
{
      class Cell
      {
           public:
           Game *game;
      };
      class Cells : public std::list<Cell *>
      {
            Game *game;
            operator += (Cell *cell) {cell->game = this->game; ....}
      };
      Cells cells;
};
```

Comment: Deriving from standard library container classes isn't really the best idea.  You have to be very careful (i.e. protected or private derivation) are you can introduce memory leaks since their destructors are not virtual.

Comment: If you embed the derived class in an object, the right destructor will be called.

Comment: Yes, if you contain an object that is known by the derived class, the correct destructor will be called.  If you contain an object that is known by pointer to the base (say via a smart pointer), then the wrong destructor will be called.  One of the principles I adhere to when I design an interface is: Make it hard to use in an unsafe way.  This will save you and others time farther down the road.

Comment: Then include an instance of std::list<<cell *>> in Cells as a (private) member variable.